# Webpack 4 - node_modules in parent folder. How to create vendors chunk?

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification, webpack-4

I have this configuration in my webpack.config.js

```
vendors : {
    test : /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
    chunks: 'initial',
    name: 'vendors',
    priority: 10,
    enforce: true,
    minChunks : 2,
},
```

which worked fine when the node_modules were inside the project folder. Now, I have moved the *node_modules* to the parent folder to share it among other projects. However, the *vendors.js* file is not created.

I experimenting with the line  `test : /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/` but no success. I assume I need to update this line, so that webpack checks the parent folder for modules.

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like this. Because if you dont put slash then node will search for node modules in parent directory.

test : /node_modules[\/]/,

Check this out
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/681

Comment: Thanks! I found another issue. I am testing this with a new project, and the option "minChunks:2" was the problem. I simply didn't use any module 2x. I changed to 1 for now and now i get vendors.js